# Adding something to the community wiki

Tags: discussion

I posted a reasonably sized answer to [I am new to IOT and am looking for some platform I can use to learn how to create IOT applications](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/i-am-new-to-iot-and-am-looking-for-some-platform-i-can-use-to-learn-how-to-creat)

As I posted it, I knew that it would be closed (currently held) as it is far, far too broad.

I answered because I wanted to help, forget about points.

"How do I get started" is definitely a FAQ, and one with a myriad answers.

Is there any way to combine of such questions into the community wiki, so that we can point future n00bs at it? I realize that there can never be a complete answer, but surely some help is better than none? And we are here to help people, after all.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer now, but I agree that these kinds of questions ought definitely to be welcome.  My issue with that particular question was that, like you said, it's really broad.  Make the question specify a precise issue, and I don't care how clueless the OP is on how to proceed (well, maybe within limits :) ).  As for a community wiki... It could be done, but with caution.  New users judge what they can post by what has been posted in the past (and rightly so), which means that we have a certain burden of not producing content whose style we don't want duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Answers like this do not need to be CW, we just need to be wary of attracting many low quality answers to any question which does not have a specific answer. The issue in this case is the question - and I think the problem with the question is the research gap. To me, although I don't have a specific answer, I assume that there are tons of platforms which make ideal tester devices for AWS. This makes me assume that the OP has not done any research.

How do I get started will be a common question, and is for sure too general. There are just too many points in the stack that a specific person will want to develop their skills. Right through from custom ASIC, to data learning and eventually up to packaged platforms. Cross this with the target market (smart home, cities, building, industrial, agricultural) and there is a huge space.

This site is not best suited for writing tutorials, be it for AWS test data or any other niche. Ideally, the answer to this question would be to link to the appropriate AWS documentation and explain how it is relevant. Otherwise we are inviting every eval platform to provide an answer.

In the spirit of what we have been doing with closed questions all along on this site, I think the best approach is to try and edit the *question* so that this answer is good and specific. Then the OP gets a few points, and pointers about what the site expectations are, and might go on to ask a question that is actually relevant to them.

Also, I don't have a huge issue with closed but answered questions. They persist, and don't necessarily need to be deleted. We can still link to/from them, and this can help to guide others in the future.